# using redis-node (nodejs) with utf-8/16 (russian, chinese, japanese characters)

Tags: node.js, utf-8, redis

Has anyone successuflly used Russian/Chinese/Japanese characters with redis-node or any other redis library (using nodejs) to store/receive messages to & from Redis (2.0 and above)?  I believe encoding/decoding of these messages is upto the client, not Redis.  If so, do any of the libraries provide this encoding/decoding or is there another library one can use for this purpose?  Any working code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I will try wit utf-8/16 encoding/decoding prior to redis inserts and revert accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using utf-8 with redis works - if you use redis-cli, make sure that you pass in raw as the parameter to read the russian/chinese/japanese characters (otherwise those characters will not appear correctly in redis-cli).  You can retrieve them correctly using an API like Jedis/redis-node etc.
Hope this helps!